# How can I compress jQuery hide() and then fadeIn() to a single line?

Tags: jquery

I'm adding new rows to a table using jQuery and have the rows fading in as I want but only by making two calls, the first uses `after` to add the new row at the end of my table and then I use `hide` followed by `fadeIn` to get the effect. I want to compress this

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $.get('@Url.Action("AddCalculatorRow", "Workshop", 
                           new { id = Model.Id } )', function (data) {
            $('.calculator').find("tbody tr:last").after(data);
            $('.calculator').find("tbody tr:last").hide().fadeIn(2000);
        });
    });
});
```

the duplication tells me there must be a more elegant way to achieve the look. However if I make that

```
$('.calculator').find("tbody tr:last").after(data).hide().fadeIn(2000);
```

then the row that's added is shown instantly and what was the last row hides and fades in... which looks awful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just target the next element after adding new content.

```
$('.calculator').find("tbody tr:last").after(data).next().hide().fadeIn(2000);
```

or swap it around:

```
$(data).hide().appendTo('.calculator tbody').fadeIn(2000);
```

It would also be smart to go ahead and parse data before you use it, but that's completely optional:

```
$($.parseHTML(data)).hide().appendTo('.calculator tbody').fadeIn(2000);
```

Comment: The first suggestion works, swapping it round was bizaar, I got a row above and below.  Can you elaborate on what you mean by parsing the data?

Comment: do you have multiple tbody tags? using `$.parseHTML()` just makes sure it gets parsed properly. For example, it solves a memory leak in IE10 when you parse an entire document with `$(htmlstring)`.

Comment: I *did*; though I only added one - so something was adding another set. I removed the one I put in and that sorted it. The terser version works great now. I like that it's more compact too.